# qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.3-online.run cannot execute binary file, getting Exec format error

Tags: 15.10, raspberrypi

I am installing the library: `qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.3-online.run` on one raspberry pi-2, with operative system ubuntu mate 15.10, but to execute the command `./qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.3-online.run` in one terminal, present the error:

```
bash: ./qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.3-online.run: 1: cannot execute binary file:Exec format error
```

I check the permissions of executing of the file and they are O.k..

With the command `uname -a` the system answers

```
Linux ribemat-desktop 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 arm7vl armv7l arm7vl GNU/Linux.
```

The error is same to the install file `*.run`, `*.bin`.

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The qt installation you're using is built for x86 architecture, but the RaspberryPi has an arm11 processor, so you will need to cross-compile qt in order to execute it on the Pi.

I've rather looked at the route of building my applications on a normal laptop and cross-compiling those to run on the Pi, rather than putting Qt install onto the Pi.

Try this link:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-build-a-gcc-4-7-toolchain-for-cross-compiling

It shows the procedure to build and install a Arm cross-compiler using gcc onto your system. I've only just finished building it, and haven't confirmed 100% functionality as yet, but will update this post once I have.